# How to extract words from string matching those contained in an array of forbidden words (and remove any left-over whitespace)?

Tags: javascript, string, sanitization

How would you extract certain words from a string, given an array of forbidden words.

Consider the following Woody Allen quote as an example:

```
Love is the answer, 
but while you are waiting for the answer 
sex raises some pretty good questions
```

And this is the array of words to extract from the string:

```
var forbidden = new Array("is", "the", "but", "you", 
"are", "for", "the", "some", "pretty");
```

How would you extract any words from the string, any remove any left-over whitespace so that you end up with this result:

```
Love answer, while waiting answer sex raises good questions
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var quote = "Love is the answer, but while you are waiting for the answer sex raises some pretty good questions";
 var forbidden = new Array("is", "the", "but", "you", "are", "for", "the", "some", "pretty");

 var isForbidden = {};
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < forbidden.length; i++) {
     isForbidden[forbidden[i]] = true;
 }

 var words = quote.split(" ");
 var sanitaryWords = [];

 for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     if (!isForbidden[words[i]]) {
          sanitaryWords.push(words[i]);
     }
 }

 alert(sanitaryWords.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var quote = "Love is the answer,\nbut while you are waiting for the answer\nsex raises some pretty good questions";

var forbidden = ["is", "the", "but", "you", "are", "for", "the", "some", "pretty"];

var reg = RegExp('\\b(' + forbidden.join('|') + ')\\b\\s?', 'g');

alert(quote.replace(reg, ''));
```

**Try it:** http://jsbin.com/isero5/edit